# Solr cloud 4.8 inconsistant results

Tags: solr

We are using solr cloud with solr version 4.8, we have 2 shard/2 replica servers in Solr Cloud. During two consecutive request to the solr cloud, the "total results" number varies.

1) As per my understanding this can happen when the leader and the replica have inconsistant number of results.

2) This inconsistant number of docs between leader and replica can happen only when replica is recovering. Should a request be sent to a node which is recovering.

Since this is happening on our live setup, we tend to question how much can we rely on solr. What could be causing this and what's the fix.

Regards

Comment: Does your query include a search feature which is not supported by SolrCloud?

Comment: @MattMcKnight no, there are all standard select queries.